# Should I dismiss keyboard popping up automatically in a react native app in componentWillMount()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Basically I have an issue where a component of mine is having the keyboard pop-up on the android version of my app screen. I'm guessing the iOS version automatically dismisses it.

Since I am semi-new to react ecosystem, I was thinking I should trigger this event before the screen is even rendered via componentWillMount(). Is that a proper usage of my function, and will it work? If not what is another way to go about handling this issue? I have the common dismissKeyboard function below for reference, and I want to trigger this before the screen renders.

```
_dismissKeyboard = () => {
        TextInputState.blurTextInput(TextInputState.currentlyFocusedField());
    };
```

Comment: then again life cycle methods are more about updating state, whereas I just want to disable the keyboard throughout the entire screen

Comment: I see no reason why you shouldn't do this, but in any case, the keyboard is being displayed for a reason (a.k.a. a text input component is gaining focus automatically). Are you sure you are not having an `autoFocus={true}` in any component?

Comment: Then again, according to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount): "Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.". Dismissing the keyboard might be considered a side-effect of some sort.

Comment: Im definitely sure Im not having autoFocus={true}. That was my first hunch :(

Comment: Can you maybe post your `render` method or any other relevant ones? It might help to find the error.